# Get user by name

Tags: users

I have a user_reference field in a content type.
I want to remove all the users from it except from current user and administrators.
Only administrator should see the complete users list.

I started by checking id=f current user is ad administrator.

```
function usersfilter_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
     global $user;
     if (in_array('administrator', array_values($user)){
        return; //administrator
     }
```

Now I prepare the array that will be the new users list (can I just remove oart of the users instead?) and get the users list:

```
    $newUsers = array();
    $existingUsers = $form['field_users']['und']['#options'];
```

Finally I go over all the users. If this is the current user name, I'll add it.
How can I check if this user is an administrator?

```
foreach ($existingUsers as &$existingUser) {
  if ($existingUser = $user->name) {
    $newUsers[] = $existingUser;
    break;
  }

  // If administrator, add to the list.
}
```

Comment: As side note, there is a typo in your last snippet: You are using `$existingUser = $user->name` in the control statement when you should use `$existingUser == $user->name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal you should use the [`user_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7) function with a specific permission to find out if the user has a certain level of access, not check their roles directly. The result is the same but it's just considered better practice to use the in-built permissions system.

You can use the [`user_load_by_name()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load_by_name/7) function to load the user if you don't have the account id/user object already, e.g.:

```
$account = user_load_by_name($user_name);
if (user_access('access administration pages', $account)) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: thank you. that works.
Just for documentation, here is the complete code http://pastebin.com/JH8x9RHz

Comment: @Tibo The reason `user_access()` should be used is that a permission could be added to more than one role. using `user_access()`, the code doesn't change (the permission is still the same, e.g. "administer nodes"); using `in_array('administrator', $roles)`, the code could need to be changed, as you could need to check if the user don't have other roles too.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what roles the user have with code similar to the following one:

```
global $user;

if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
  // The user is an administrator.
}
```

Comment: the variable $existingUser is just the user name. not the complete user object, right? so it has no property named "roles".

Comment: you get the current user always by using 
global $user; 
that object will get you the roles property. edited my answer to reflect that.